# Set default browser in C++ builder 5

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-5

Im using C++ builder 5 and got some links in my program. I want these links to open in the default system browser or in firefox if default is no option.

I used:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "http://maps.google.nl/maps?f=q&hl=nl&q=", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

But for some links it will not work with the code that already exists.

```
// this is not working
     case 4: if(Qry_shipment->RecordCount == 0){return;}
                         webaddress =    "http://maps.google.nl/maps?f=q&hl=nl&q=";

                    //we need the info from clicked shipment-not from overflow
                    if(Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tstohn")->AsString == pAuthorization[7])
                    {
                            webaddress =    webaddress
                                            + Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tslpla")->AsString  + ","
                                            + Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tslzcd")->AsString  + ","
                                            + Qry_shipment->FieldByName("lalaad")->AsString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            webaddress =    webaddress
                                            + Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tsupla")->AsString  + ","
                                            + Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tsuzcd")->AsString  + ","
                                            + Qry_shipment->FieldByName("lalos")->AsString;

                    }
                    break;
```

Is there maybe a pice of code so i can define the default browser for the program it self so i dont have to edit all the links.

Comment: What's the problem you have exactly? Does a browser show up but doesn't open your page (make sure your URL is constructed correctly), or does ShellExecute fail on its own?

Comment: ShellExecute *will* open the URL using the default browser. If your code fails when you're adding the params from the database, then tell us the complete URL that's failing. As I'm not psychic I cannot deduce the contents of your database...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++ Builder 5, I assume that the host OS is Windows. Thus, there is no need to care about multiplatform issues.

Windows has a "start" command. Depending on the argument, it will launch the associated executable. So you could try with just:

```
system( "start http://maps.google.nl/" );
```

As long as the argument starts with `http://`, I don't think you'll have any problem. You can probably move this to trick to `ShellExecute()`, but unfortunately I don't have a C++ Builder here to check it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @stan I want the program to open the default system browser and not IE. I dont know how to rewrite the code so it will work.

Comment: But in my system (Windows 7), it opens the default browser, which is firefox in my case...

Comment: yea on my system aswell but how can i add parameters? 
+ Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tsupla")->AsString  + ","
+ Qry_shipment->FieldByName("tsuzcd")->AsString  + ","
+ Qry_shipment->FieldByName("lalos")->AsString;

Comment: Do you mean as in the following example? system( "start http://www.google.com/#hl=es&q=teddybears" ) In this example you have the parameters hl=es and q=teddybears... where is the problem? (beware that stackoverflow hides the http:// part)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question (and additional comment) correctly, you currently encounter the problem with `ShellExecute`, which launches IE instead of a default browser. If so, here is what you can try.

1. Default system browser is registered in the system Registry at the path `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command`. There could possibly be another locations, but you can start with this one and see if it works on most of the systems. You should read this entry from your code, and you'll get an exact command line to start default browser.
2. Windows supports a special type of files - `*.url` files (they are just text files). They can be used to open a specific url by means of default browser. You can generate a temporary `*.url` file with the following content:

> [InternetShortcut]
>
> URL=http://www.domain.com/path?query

Having such a file you can execute it with `ShellExecute`as usual.

Comment: the default browser works perfect but i dont know how to add any parameters to the shellexecute command. so i can add stuff to the url.

Comment: @user1746378 From your question it's clear that you append parameters as you need, then you can execute the browser with this URL. Either way I mentioned should work. For example, if you get from the Registry `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\chrome.exe" -- "%1"`, then just replace %1 with your URL and run the entire command. Using internet shortcat approach, just place your complete URL in the `URL` key.

Comment: but isnt there a way to tell the program to not use IE and just use another browser

Comment: @user1746378 Both methods I showed above run Chrome (not IE) on my PC. If IE is the default browser on your PC, the methods will launch IE.

Comment: Ok, if you take a look at the code i provided how would you implement the internet shortcut? Could you provide a example?

Comment: @user1746378, after your concatenated the strings into URL, write it into a temporary text file with abovementioned structure (don't forget `url` extension), and execute it, then delete the file.

Comment: Then restate your question, please. It becomes unclear, what is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ShellExecute()`, set the `lpOperation` parameter to `NULL` instead of `"open"`.  That will execute the `http://` protocol's **true** default action, as `"open"` is not always the default registered verb.